# scp remote file to local machine

Tags: linux, bash, scp

as a part of script I'm trying to copy a file from remote site.
But got an error.
To me that sounds bit strange as everything sounds ok:

```
#aaa="/path/to/some file with spaces(and brackets).txt"
....
#scp user@example.com:"$aaa" /test/
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `scp -f /path/to/some file with spaces.txt'
```

upd: problem with brackets...

Comment: Please add the complete script

Comment: Put a `set -x` in your script before the problem so the exact command be executed is printed out on the screen?

Comment: it doesn't really matters, at the moment i'm trying to debug that just from command line, and if you will just type in bash lines starting with "#" you will get the same error

Comment: You need to have the brackets escaped or quoted too, as bash wants to take action on them

Comment: `aaa="'/path/to/some file with spaces(and brackets).txt'"` should escape it twice, once in single quotes, once in double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape each spaces and brackets :

```
#!/bin/bash

aaa='/path/to/some\ file\ with\ spaces\(and brackets\).txt'
scp user@example.com:"$aaa" /test/
```

By the way, a more friendly alternative would be to enclose `$aaa` with single quotes in addition to double quotes :

```
#!/bin/bash

aaa='/path/to/some file with spaces(and brackets).txt'
scp user@example.com:"'$aaa'" /test/
```

Comment: echo $aaa |sed -r "s/\(/\\\(/g"|sed -r "s/\)/\\\)/g"|sed -r "s/ /\\\ /g"

Comment: @swap What do you mean with this `sed` command ?

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me.  I think you just need to escape the spaces, brackets or anything else and you should be good.

```
#!/bin/bash

aaa="/tmp/untitled\ text\ 2.txt"

scp -r user@example.com:"$aaa" .
```

Comment: in that case you will copy local file to remote server

Comment: Yes, that is the reverse from question !

Comment: Updated answer above to get remote file.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file on my remote host with the literal name `"/tmp/some file with spaces(and brackets).txt~.

If you double+single quote the name like so I was able to transfer it.  Inspired by this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/234876/escaping-spaces-in-a-remote-path-when-using-rsync-over-a-remote-ssh-connection).

```
/tmp$ scp remotehost:"'/tmp/some file with spaces(and brackets).txt'" .
some file with spaces(and brackets).txt          100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

With a variable

```
/tmp$ aaa="/tmp/some file with spaces(and brackets).txt"
/tmp$ scp puppet:"'$aaa'" .
some file with spaces(and brackets).txt               100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```